# Max number of query steps in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am having some trouble querying some data in Laravel.

I start my query doing the following:

```
$query = User::whereRole('advertiser');
```

When I query for example `$usersall = $query->whereHave_pics('1')->get();`
Then I also get users that have 0 in `have_pics`

The `$query` can consist of a long string of `where` queries that are dynamic depending on the users choices. Some of these `where` queries, the users that have 0 in have_pics do qualify for, but when I end the query with whereHave_pics('1'), shouldn't I only get the users that have '1' in `Have_pics`?

**What I am wondering, is, if there is a max number of steps that laravel can handle in the query builder?**

For example, if I but whereHave_pics('1') at the beginning of the query, like this:

```
$query = User::whereRole('advertiser')->whereHave_pics('1'); 
   /* More queries are added */
$usersall = $query->get();
```

Then it completely ignores the `whereHave_pics` but not the `whereRole`...
If I do it at the end of the query, like this:

```
$query = User::whereRole('advertiser'); 
   /* More queries are added */
$usersall = $query->whereHave_pics('1')->get();
```

Then it is dependent on the users choices that also creates queries.

I have been trying a ton of different work arounds, like changing the query model, e.g. instead of `whereHave_pics('1')` I have done `where('have_pics', '1')` or `where('have_pics', true)` etc.

I have no idea what to try next.

---

This is the complete function, that queries the users

```
public function search_adv(Request $request, $locale = 'dk') {

    App::setLocale($locale);

    $hair_queries = [
    ['input' => 'blonde', 'operator' => '=', 'field' => 'haircolor'],
    ['input' => 'brown', 'operator' => '=', 'field' => 'haircolor'],
    ['input' => 'red', 'operator' => '=', 'field' => 'haircolor'],
    ['input' => 'dark', 'operator' => '=', 'field' => 'haircolor'],
    ];

    $eye_queries = [
    ['input' => 'green', 'operator' => '=', 'field' => 'eyecolor'],
    ['input' => 'brown', 'operator' => '=', 'field' => 'eyecolor'],
    ['input' => 'blue', 'operator' => '=', 'field' => 'eyecolor'],
    ['input' => 'hazel', 'operator' => '=', 'field' => 'eyecolor'],
    ['input' => 'silver', 'operator' => '=', 'field' => 'eyecolor'],
    ['input' => 'amber', 'operator' => '=', 'field' => 'eyecolor'],
    ];


    $query = User::whereRole('advertiser'); 

    /* HAIRCOLOR */
    $hair = 0;
    foreach($hair_queries as $filter) {
        if($hair == 0) {
        if(!empty($request->input($filter['input']))) {
            $query = $query->where(
                $filter['field'],
                $filter['operator'],
                $filter['input']
            );
        }
        }
        if(!empty($request->input($filter['input']))) {
            $hair++;
        }
    }

    if ($hair >= 2) {
    foreach($hair_queries as $filter){
        if(!empty(request()->input($filter['input']))){
            $query = $query->orWhere(
                $filter['field'],
                $filter['operator'],
                $filter['input']
            );
        }
    }
    }
    /* END HAIR COLOR */

    /* EYECOLOR */
    $eye = 0;
    foreach($eye_queries as $filter) {
        if($eye == 0) {
        if(!empty($request->input($filter['input']))) {
            $query = $query->where(
                $filter['field'],
                $filter['operator'],
                $filter['input']
            );
        }
        }
        if(!empty($request->input($filter['input']))) {
            $eye++;
        }
    }

    if ($eye >= 2) {
    foreach($eye_queries as $filter){
        if(!empty(request()->input($filter['input']))){
            $query = $query->orWhere(
                $filter['field'],
                $filter['operator'],
                $filter['input']
            );
        }
    }
    }
    /* END EYE COLOR */


    $usersall = $query->whereHave_pics('1')->get();

    return view('search', compact('usersall'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you need to understand how where chaining and orWhere chaining works in Laravel.

When you say `$query->where(..a..)->orWhere(..b..)->where(..c..)->orWhere(..d..)` it will evaluate to: `(a || (b && c) || d)`. Where you may have intended `((a || b) && (c || d))` or you may have intended `((a && c) || b || d)`. This is why when you need advanced where clauses, use where closures and [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#parameter-grouping)

Comment: Okay, I see. Do you have a source for the where closures? a quick google search didn't come up with anything

Comment: Click on the parameter grouping link in my post

Comment: Okay, I saw that but I thought it was to different things -- where closures Or parameter grouping :)